# Evaluate the following contour integral:

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $\gamma(z_0,R)$ denote the circular contour $z_0+Re^{it}$ for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. 
Evaluate 
$$
\int_{\gamma(0,1)}\dfrac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+4)}dz
$$

I've tried to use the binomial expansion with $(z+\frac{1}{z})(z^2+4)^{-1}$ but then I'm not sure what to do. Any help will be great.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(z) = \frac{z^2+1}{z^2+4}$$
is analytic on the unit disc, so Cauchy's integral formula shows that the integral equals $2\pi i f(0) = \pi i/2$. (No need for the residue theorem)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).  The only pole within $\gamma(0,1)$ is at $z=0$.  The residue there is 1/4, so the value of the integral is $i \pi/2$.